# Получить прямую ссылку на YouTube-видео

Tags: php, javascript, видео, youtube, youtube-api

Нужно получить прямую ссылку на видео с youtube.com.

За основу взял [этот скрипт](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547722/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE-youtube).

С некоторыми видео получается, а с некоторыми — нет.
Вот пример двух видеороликов:

1. [Работает нормально](http://youtube.com/watch?v=ZdJ7zga2yGg).
2. [Прямая ссылка генерируется, но не работает](http://youtube.com/watch?v=ZICPIa4BHNo).

Ссылка на пример моего скрипта — mikkel.pp.ua/youtube/

Схема работы:

1. Пользователь вводит ссылку в input и жмёт кнопку.
2. К api.php (код api.php ниже) прилетает AJAX, и в ответ отдаётся
   содержимое файла с информацией о ролике.
3. JS вытаскивает прямую ссылку из того, что вернул api.php (содержимое
   файла).

Исходный код api.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['orig_link'])){
    $pattern = '/(.*)v=(.*)/';
    preg_match($pattern,$_POST['orig_link'],$matches);
    $file = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id='.$matches[2]);
    echo $file;
}
?>
```

Исходный код JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#getlink').click(function(){     

        var orig_link = $('#orig_link').val();

        // отправляем AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'api.php',
            data: {'orig_link':orig_link},
            success: function(str){

                //функция для создания уникальных ключей. дальше рассказано зачем.
                var genKey = function(key, arr){
                    if(arr[key]){
                        key = key+1;
                        return genKey(key, arr);
                    } else {
                        return key;
                    }   
                }

                //из строки запроса делает ассоциативный массив. 
                var parseQuery = function(s){
                    var t = s.split('&');
                    var query = {}; 
                    for(var k in t){
                        var t2 = t[k].split('=');
                        //выяснилось, что в данных под url_encoded_fmt_stream_map ключи повторяются (url=*&url=*&url=*). Чтобы избежать перезаписи ключей применил простейшую функцию genKey.
                        var key = genKey(t2[0], query);
                        query[key] = t2[1];
                    }    
                    return query;
                };

                //получаем массив данных раскодируя исходную строку
                var tmp = parseQuery(str);

                //под ключом url_encoded_fmt_stream_map находим интересующий нас список урлов. он в urlencoded-виде.
                var encodedStreamMap = tmp['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'];

                //превращаем с массив данные из url_encoded_fmt_stream_map, предварительно сделав urldecode строки.
                var stream_map = parseQuery(decodeURIComponent(encodedStreamMap));

                //под ключом "url" в массиве находится ссылка на самое качественное видео (по моим двум экспериментам, по крайней мере)
                var url = decodeURIComponent(stream_map['url']);

                // показываем ссылку
                $('#link').val(url);
                $('#download').attr('href',url);
                $('#download').show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Кстати, сервис http://ru.savefrom.net/ успешно сохраняет оба видео. Только не понятно, как он генерирует ссылку. У него она имеет вид:

> redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&upn=uXwJQNLfR_k&lmt=1473473028543269&expire=1474060686&mime=video%2Fmp4&nh=IgpwcjA0Lm9yZDEyKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&itag=22&dur=28838.022&initcwndbps=1977500&sparams=dur%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&gcr=us&ipbits=0&mt=1474038424&pl=21&mv=m&id=o-ADiQkIs_e6v2HOTx5aaWu6An7ah1nqc4gixNWY-g8CMr&ms=au&key=yt6&ip=50.31.8.155&mm=31&mn=sn-vgqsenls&signature=CE290F413C21A39FC90D1495234897D9250B7676.DC407C7A7EDEC68CEE2E43EF0D3A4C1EB727FC10&title=Deep+Sleep+Music%2C+Peaceful+Music%2C+Relaxing%2C+Meditation+Music%2C+Sleep+Meditation+Music%2C+8+Hour%2C+%E2%98%AF2912

А "мой" скрипт выдаёт вот такое:

> r3---sn-pivhx-n8vl.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mt=1474038399&mv=u&sparams=dur%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mime=video%2Fmp4&ms=au&ip=91.106.207.13&requiressl=yes&itag=22&mm=31&mn=sn-pivhx-n8vl&id=o-AKVNfny3orfuG3yOa0O9GVyw7sRz9IWyBbQTHawNheQA&pl=24&source=youtube&upn=g9uS50urQ5U&gcr=ru&key=yt6&lmt=1473473028543269&ratebypass=yes&expire=1474060744&ipbits=0&dur=28838.022

Answer (score 1):

Я применяю более простые ссылки YouTube, например www.youtube.com/embed/ххх. Для предварительной загрузки вы можете применять в head: 
link rel=preconnect href=//www.youtube.com/embed/ххх